# not able to upload files into mediawiki -- weird one

Tags: mediawiki

Completely frustrating me.

When I try and upload a small jpeg file I get the following error:

```
Warning: wfMkdirParents: failed to mkdir "/usr/local/mediawiki-1.20.5/images/5/5d" mode 0777 in /usr/local/mediawiki-1.20.5/includes/GlobalFunctions.php on line 2546
```

CentOS 6.4
MediaWiki 1.20.5
PHP 5.5.0RC1 (apache2handler)
MySQL 5.5.31

php.ini

```
safe_mode = off;
file_uploads = On
max_file_uploads = 20
```

localsettings.php

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";
```

images folder

```
chown apache:apache images/
chmod 755 -R images/ (threw error)
chmod 777 -R images/ (threw error)
```

I've restart apache and still cannot upload. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Has it _ever_ worked? Did you check the `audit.log`?

Comment: It's `chmod` for permissions, not `chown`.

Comment: "chown -R" and "chmod -R", please :)

Comment: And because it's centos, "setenforce permissive"

Comment: Yes I used chmod it was a typo.  GioMac can you elaborate what you mean setenforce permissive?

Comment: # sestatus | grep -i mode
Current mode:  enforcing
Mode from config file:  enforcing

# setenforce 0
# sestatus | grep -i mode
Current mode:  permissive
Mode from config file: enforcing

Then I tried uploading and it worked!  Is it possible to get upload working in enforcing mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by SELinux, rather than setting SELinux to only log and not enforce policy (permissive mode) you can modify the labels on the file system to allow the Apache to write the location while SELinux is enforcing:

Assuming `/usr/local/mediawiki-1.20.5/images` is the location you want to allow write access to:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/usr/local/mediawiki-1.20.5/images(/.*)?"
```

Will change the SELinux context on the directory and anything below it, and

```
restorecon -Rv /usr/local/mediawiki-1.20.5/images
```

Will relabel the files and directories as per the SELinux context.